# Android/Kotlin: Why is the lambda syntax different for .setOnClickListener() and .observe()?

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, onclicklistener, anonymous-class

Hey guys my first post here. I'm new to Kotlin, so this might be a stupid question so bear with me guys.

I am a bit confused by the lambda syntaxes used in Kotlin.

For example, in the setOnClickListener(), we directy pass a lambda block:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.insert(MyData("Title","Desc",android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float))            
        }
```

But in the .observe() method, we do not pass a lambda block but an object of Observer (with lambda?) :

```
viewModel.getAllData().observe(this,
            Observer<List<MyData>> { t -> myAdapter.submitList(t)
})
```

I tried this anonymous class approach first but the IDE suggested I convert it to lamda(above).

```
viewModel.getAllData().observe(this, object: Observer<List<MyData>>{
            override fun onChanged(t: List<MyData>?) {
                myAdapter.submitList(t)
            }
        })
```

So what's the difference between these two ways of using the .observe() method? We are still passing an object of anonymous class Observer in both the cases right?

Also, why is the lambda syntax different for the onClickListener() and .observe() methods when these interfaces are defined the same way?:

OnClickListener Interface:

```
  public interface OnClickListener {
        /**
         * Called when a view has been clicked.
         *
         * @param v The view that was clicked.
         */
        void onClick(View v);
    }
```

Observer Interface:

```
public interface Observer<T> {
    /**
     * Called when the data is changed.
     * @param t  The new data
     */
    void onChanged(T t);
}
```

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Because of `Observer` has **generic** type.

Comment: You can write it as `viewModel.getAllData().observe(this) { myAdapter.submitList(it) }`. If IDE complains upgrade `kotlin-gradle-plugin` and kotlin dependency to `1.4.10`. If you're a developer with java background and wondering why lambda expression syntax is different in kotlin then read about `higher order functions` and `trailing lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

The one you are using is on `package androidx.lifecycle;` on the `LiveData.java` class.

There is another on `package androidx.lifecycle` in the file `LiveData.kt` that is an extension that would yield the sugar syntax resulting in

```
observable.observe(viewLifeCyleOwner) {
    //...
}
```

For using it you have to import

```
import androidx.lifecycle.observe
```

The difference is 1 parameter lambda can ignore the argument if is not used, in the observer case there are 2 parameters, so that is why there is a handy dandy extension.

You can read more about lambdas in the following [link](https://antonioleiva.com/lambdas-kotlin-android/)